# Why variables start out with random values in C

Tags: c, variables, random, declaration, default-value

I think this is wrong, it should start as NULL and not with a random value. In the case that you have a pointer with a random memory address as its default value it could be a very dangerous thing, no?

Comment: If you're going to go as far as to force initialization then you should not allow NULL at all.

Comment: *"I think this is wrong"* about a language still going strong after 35+ years. C isn't perfect, it has its faults, but it is worth understand the whys behind some of these decisions before issuing a blanket statement like that. In the case of c that means understanding what programming was like in the early 1970s.

Comment: I guess uninitialized values are less a problem than undefined behavior. After all, warnings are there to save you at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. C is a very efficient language, one that has traditionally been faster that a lot of other languages. One of the reasons for this is that it doesn't do too much on it's own. The programmer controls this.

In the case of initialization, C variables are not initialized to a random value. Rather, they are not initialized and so they contain whatever was at the memory location before.

If you wanted to initialize a variable to, say, 1 in your program, then it would be inefficient if the variable had already been initialized to zero or null. That would mean it was initialized twice.

Comment: This is less of an objection today than it once was, because modern compilers are certainly smart enough to leave out any initialisation that is subsequently overwritten without being read.

Comment: Perhaps that's one of many reasons why C is less popular today than it was.

Comment: @caf: You missed the key class of algorithms where lack of initialization is essential, which a compiler surely cannot check.

Comment: @R.: I'm not sure what you're referring to - my comment was regarding the "initialised twice" inefficiency argument.

Answer (score 6):

The variables start out uninitialized because that's the fastest way - why waste the CPU cycles on initialization if you're going to write another value there anyway?

If you want a variable to be initialized after creation, just initialize it. :)

About it being a dangerous thing: Every good compiler will warn you if you try to use a variable without initialization.

Comment: Not if you turn off warnings :)  I have seen this too often.  Turn on warnings in someone else's project and watch them roll in.

Comment: Well, shooting yourself in the foot was never ever prohibited in C/C++ :)

Answer (score 2):

Execution speed and overhead (or lack thereof) are the main reasons why.  C is notorious for letting you walk off the proverbial cliff because it always assumes that the user knows better than it does.

Note that if you declared the variable as `static` it actually *is* guaranteed to be initialized to 0.

Comment: But you should still initialize it to 0 explicitly anyway. You're writing for people, not machines.

Comment: I meant it as an interesting side effect not as a style guideline

Answer (score 1):

Variables start out with a random value because you are just handed a block of memory and told to deal with it yourself. It has whatever value that block of memory had before hand. Why should the program waste time setting the value to some arbitrary default when you are likely going to set it yourself later?

Answer (score 1):

The design choice is performance, and it is one of the many reasons why C isn't the preferred language for most projects.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with "if C were being designed today" or with efficiency of one initialization. Instead think of something like

```
void foo()
{
    struct bar *ptrs[10000];
    /* do something where only a few indices end up actually getting used */
}
```

Any language that forces useless initialization on you is doomed to be slow as hell for algorithms that can make use of sparse arrays where you don't care about the majority of the values, and have an easy way of knowing which values you care about.

If you don't like my example with such a large object on the stack, substitute `malloc` instead. It has the same semantics with regard to initialization.

In either case, if you want zero-initialization, you can get it with `{0}` or `calloc`.

Answer (score 0):

It was a design choice made many ears ago, probably for efficiency reasons.

Statically allocated variables (globals and statics) are initialized to 0 if there's no explicit initialization - this could be justified even taking efficiency into account becuase it only occurs once. I'd guess the thinking was that for automatic variables (locals) that are allocated each time a scope is entered, implicit initialization was considered something that might cost too much and therefore should be left to the programmer's responsibility.

If C were being designed today, I wouldn't be surprised if that design decision were changed - especially since compilers are intelligent enough today to be able to optimize away an initialization that gets overwritten before any other use (or potential use).

However, there are so many C compiler toolchains that follow the spec of not initializing automatically, it would be foolish for a compiler to perform implicit initialization to a 'useful' value (like 0 or NULL).  That would just encourage people targeting that tool chain to write code that didn't work correctly on other tool chains.

However, compilers *can* initialize local variables, and they often do. It's just that they initialize the locals to a values that's not generally useful (especially, that doesn't set a pointer to the null pointer). That kind of initialization isn't useful in writing your programming logic against, and it's not intended for that.  It's intended to cause deterministic and reproducible errors so that if you erroneously use values that have been set by implicit initialization, you'll be able to find it easily in test/debug.

Usually this compiler behavior is turned on only for debug builds; I could see an argument being made for turning it on in release builds as well - particular if the release build can still optimize it away when the compiler can prove that the implicit initialized value is never used.